# Adding script/web resources for ScriptControl implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm not quite familiar with asp.net ajax, so my question might be a silly one.

I'm working on the asp.net ajax control library for self-educational purposes and it is not quite clear to me how to add script/web resources to my class library project.

I've added the following lines to the AssenblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: WebResource("BlackGoat.UI.Controls.TooltipControl.Tooltip.js","text/javascript")]
[assembly: ScriptResource("BlackGoat.UI.Controls.TooltipControl.Tooltip.js","BlackGoat.UI.Tooltip", "BlackGoat.UI.Resource")]
```

The relative path to the javascript file is `Controls\TooltipControl\Tooltip.js`, however the directories `Controls` and `TooltipControl` are not namespace providers so I'm not sure how should I specify the the js file 'namespace' in the AssemblyInfo.cs

Any clarification would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded resources do use folder names as namespaces, so if your default namespace is `BlackGoat.UI`, and folder is `Controls\TooltipControl`, it would be namespaced as `BlackGoat.UI.Controls.TooltipControl`...  that's how the framework does it internally.

Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/embeddedresources.aspx

To reference it in your AJAX control, setup the ScriptReference to use the full name as the type, and the name of the assembly (rather than using the path option).